# How to disolve lines from same layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

How can I dissolve lines from the same layer so there are no borders in the junction? For example, a crossroad shouldn't have any border (not as seen in the picture).
Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the option to *Dissolve all* when running the **Dissolve** tool:

[image: Dissolve]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try it asap

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't see to do anything. I save a shp file, load it but everything looks the same.

Comment: Strange, are the number of features still the same after you ran this? Is it possible for you to upload your shapefile publicly so people can test it?

Comment: Forget about it.I've done it again and now it works. Sorry about the mess, I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Haha no worries Dani, I just tried it again as I thought I made a mistake. Glad you got it working and no need to apologise!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?  From QGIS startup tips...

"When applying layered styles to a polyline layer, you can join intersecting lines together simply by enabling symbol levels. The image below shows a before (left) and after (right) view of an intersection when symbol levels are enabled."

[image: join intersecting pollens when rendering]
￼

Comment: Great answer if the user wants to make it look visually appealing and isn't bothered about individual attributes!